# Reference search for only modifications of a variable in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, I can do a reference search on a variable, which allows me to see every place the variable in question has been accesesed/modified. Is there a way for me to quickly see only where the variable in question has been modified? (The code base is huge...)

As an example,

```
static public int test;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    test = 4;

    if (test > 5) doNothing();
}
```

I'd only want the search to show me the line `test = 4;`, not the if test.

Comment: How many modifications can there be to a single variable, however large the codebase?  (Unless, of course, you have `public static` variables all over the place...which says bad things about the code base in the first place for pretty much this exact reason.)

Comment: I agree entirely, but that doesn't change the fact. For the public variable in question, it has over 200 access/modifications throughout the codebase!

Comment: `test` is a field, technically a type of variable sure, but it's useful to refer to it as such to distinguish from local variables. Therefore Eugene's answer does exactly what you want. It doesn't work for local variables, but if you had 200 accesses of a local, then the method needs breaking up.

Comment: @weston You are entirely correct. Eugene's answer did exactly what I wanted. I just had to wait for a while, since Stack doesn't allow one to accept an answer too quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that for fields. E.g. select "test" field, push Ctrl-H, then Java Search, select Field and Write access radio buttons and narrow down search to sources within your Workspace or specific Working set.